# ssl of one virtual host messing with other virtual host nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

**The situation is** - 
On my nginx server I have one virtual host (lets call it inbox) and another (lets call it postal) and to set up postal i followed a set of instructions. Postal has SSL enabled as you can see (see the virtual hosts site-avaibale configs file below in the "extra info" section).

- `http://inbox.go-tribalscale.com/index.html` takes me to the correct inbox folder (`/var/www/roundcube.go-tribalscale.com/public_html`)

**the problem is**
 - if i remove "/index.html" from the url it then takes me to postals directory (which loads the app therein , `/opt/postal/public`)

**solutions**
i think that the problem is in the ssl situation maybe the 443 port takes full control and the url is ignored not sure maybe you guys can help please?

**extra info**

inbox (edited as per Gerards points)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/inbox.go-tribalscale.com/public_html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  inbox.go-tribalscale.com www.inbox.go-tribalscale.com;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

     location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }

     location ^~ /data {
         deny all;
      }
}
```

postal

```
  server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name postal.outreach-hangar49.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 }

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;

    root /opt/postal/public;
    server_name postal.outreach-hangar49.com;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/postal.outreach-hangar49.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/postal.outreach-hangar49.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA512:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AESGCM:DH+AES256:RSA+AESGCM:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS;

    location / {
       client_max_body_size 50M;
       try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @puma;
    }

    location /app/assets {
       add_header Cache-Control max-age=3600;
    }

    location @puma {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

Comment: How come there is no "server_name inbox.go-tribalscale.com" in your configuration?

Comment: your right that was an error in my questions description

Answer (score 0):

Nginx will need to find suitable server context for the requested port.

So if request comes in port `80` (http) then there are multiple servers to choose from, and Nginx will choose the one with the correct `server_name`.

But if request comes in port `443` (https) then there isn't much of a chice, and regardless of the `server_name` directive, Nginx will be forced to choose incorrect server context.

**My advise to you:**

Create empty servers (with self-signed SSL certificate) that will be a failover for incorrect requests.
Only if user pass the correct `Host` header, (or server_name param for SNI) it will choose the correct context.

Example:

**default.conf**:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;
  return 404;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name _;
  ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/ssl/localhost.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/ssl/localhost.key;
  include /usr/local/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;
  return 404;
}
```

**site1.conf**:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name site1.com www.site1.com;
  return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name site1.com www.site1.com;
  ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/ssl/site1/site1.com/site1.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/ssl/site1/site1.com/site1.com.key;
  include /usr/local/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;
  ...
}
```

**site2.conf**:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name site2.com www.site2.com;
  ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/ssl/site2/site2.com/site2.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/ssl/site2/site2.com/site2.com.key;
  include /usr/local/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you visit http://inbox.go-tribalscale.com or http://inbox.go-tribalscale.com/, the following is applied:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

If you want index.html to be presented, the try_files should be

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

If you want this only when you receive a root request, you could add a new location before the current "location /":

```
location = / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

If there is an index.php in /var/www/inbox.go-tribalscale.com/public_html/, then this page is maybe the one sending you to the postal domain.